# create PDF with charts in .netcore

Tags: charts, itext, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I have been working on a .net core project using Visual Studio code, and I have to create a PDF report with charts (pie, bars etc). For the other reports in project I have used iTextSharp.LGPLv2.Core(to generate pdf). Can I use iTextSharp.LGPLv2.Core to create PDF with charts? How? Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, you will need to generate the charts yourself (choose a good plotting library), and then insert the images in a pdf (using iText).

So, your question comes down to "Can I insert an image into a pdf?"
Which you obviously can:
http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/image-examples-itext5